# container "" in pod "" is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError

Tags: kubernetes, cron, containers

container "abc-job" in pod "abc-job-manual-h9k-vbbzw" is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError

Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root (pod: "abc-job-manual-h9k-xyz-ns-nonprod(e38ece94-b411-4d70-bc29-3711f36cfe45)", container: abc-cron-job)

Below image is from cluser in pod details
[image: pod details]

below is my yaml file for cronjob

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: abc-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "10 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: abc-cron-job
            image: docker.repo1.jkl.com/xyz-services/abc/REPLACE_ME
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
            - name: spring-profile
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: spring-profile
                  key: ENV
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in yaml file, securityContext was missing, i added that and now it is working fine. Below one is the updated yaml file

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: abc-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "10 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          securityContext:
            runAsGroup: 3000
            runAsUser: 3000
          containers:
          - name: abc-cron-job
            image: docker.repo1.xyz.com/abc-services/abc-application/REPLACE_ME
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
            - name: spring-profile
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: spring-profile
                  key: ENV
            securityContext:
              privileged: false
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```